# Shared Memory in C: Shmget Issues

Tags: c, linux, shared-memory

```
int shmid;
int* locat;

//create shared memory segment
shmid = shmget(6666, size, 0666);
if (shmid < 0) {
    perror("shmget");
    exit(1);
}

locat = (int *) shmat(shmid, NULL, 0);
if (locat == (int *) -1) {
    perror("shmat");
    exit(1);
}
```

I am setting up shared memory as such, yet I keep getting this error: `shmget: No such file or directory`

This code was working fine, not sure why this occurs now.

Comment: Your shared memory creation has failed and `shmget` returned `-1`. Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7495326/understanding-shared-memory-using-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[As the man says](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/shmget.2.html)

> **IPC_CREAT**
>
> Create a new segment.  If this flag is not used, then `shmget()` will find the segment associated with key and check to see if the user has permission to access the segment.

You have to add `IPC_CREAT` to your `shmget` call

```
shmid = shmget(6666, size, IPC_CREAT | 0666);
```

You could also use the `IPC_EXCL` to ensure that the segment is newly created

> **IPC_EXCL**
>
> This flag is used with `IPC_CREAT` to ensure that this call
>                      creates the segment.  If the segment already exists, the
>                      call fails.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things :

1. When you want to initialize a shared memory ( corresponding to a particular key value ) , you have to BITWISE OR the permission number with IPC_CREAT.

Just like

```
shmget(6666 , size , 0666|IPC_CREAT);
```

2. When you want to attach the same segment ( identified by the key value ) to another process , IPC_CREAT is not mandatory as the shared memory has already been created the the logical address space.